# End of Statement Expected Error in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors

I keep getting this error on several lines of code for a program that I am working on. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or how to fix it.

Here is the section of code that is giving me the trouble.

```
    If lstRecipe.Text = "Eggs(each)" Then
        dblTotalCalories = dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 72
    ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Flour(cups)" Then
        dblTotalCalories = dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 455
    ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Milk(cups)" Then
        dblTotalCalories = dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 86
    ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Sugar(cups)" Then
        dblTotalCalories = dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 774
    ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Butter(tablespoons)" Then
        dblTotalCalories = dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 102
    End If
```

The error is specifically taking place at the += dblQuantity * ... portion of each line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `dblTotalCalories` two times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up two different ways of doing the same thing. Your code should be either
`dblTotalCalories  += dblQuantity * 72`

or

```
 dblTotalCalories = dblTotalCalories + dblQuantity * 72
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is invalid:

```
dblTotalCalories = dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 72
```

This should be

```
dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 72
```

The same applies to every other instance.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I feel so dumb, totally knew that ha. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

```
If lstRecipe.Text = "Eggs(each)" Then
     dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 72
ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Flour(cups)" Then
    dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 455
ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Milk(cups)" Then
    dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 86
ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Sugar(cups)" Then
     dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 774
ElseIf lstRecipe.Text = "Butter(tablespoons)" Then
    dblTotalCalories += dblQuantity * 102
End If
```